# How to play two mp3 audio?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2 mp3 sounds at the same time in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026105/2-mp3-sounds-at-the-same-time-in-iphone)

Hi i am creating test application where i am using two mp3 audio file.One for the background music and second file play when user clicked the button.I am using AVAudioPlayer for both and the background music is playing in appDelegate class but i am handling it from the ViewController class.Please if anybody know about this problem please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot play two compressed formats simultaneously. Try converting one of the files to AIFF, CAF or some other uncompressed format.

Comment: i am using two mp3 formats and would you please tell me what is compressed format?Should i use same AVAudioPlayer object to play these uncompressed format..