# How to play 2 sounds simultaneously

Tags: iphone, mp3, avaudioplayer

I have to play 2 sounds in my app...one for background and one for when user clicks any button.....Not i have only one sound for background and too many sounds for that button click.....all sounds are in mp3 format....

I am using AVAudioPlayer to play these sounds...

My questions are

1- Can i play these 2  mp3 sounds at same time Or should i convert that background sound to any other format....

2- I am using AVAudioPlayer to play these sounds.....so can i use 2 instances of AVAudioPlayer in same class......

Please Note that  i want that background music continuously playing.....

Please help....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1., Yes, you can even more..

2., Yes you can use AVAudioPlayer to play these, each sound source have to be allocated separately.

If you have short sounds that does not need to be stereo, you can use system sound framework to make them play.

Comment: Actually i am using those 2 sounds  both are in mp3 formats and working fine.tested on device also...I just read somewhere that apple doesn't allow to play 2 mp3 sounds at same time.so was afraid of that....give your views

Comment: No way, my app uses 3 sounds at the same time and apple loves that app.

Comment: Have a Look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026105/2-mp3-sounds-at-the-same-time-in-iphone

Comment: ok i have tested my app with device and it works fine there....does it mean i can play those sound ?

Comment: Yes, I think the basic point that apple will agree with that, is it reasonable?, if not, could be a trouble maybe.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look to below look, will helpful for you.

[2 mp3 sounds at the same time in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026105/2-mp3-sounds-at-the-same-time-in-iphone)

and blog tutorial

http://brainwashinc.wordpress.com/2009/08/14/iphone-playing-2-sounds-at-once/